# Android SeekBar changes itself progress and max randomly

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a SeekBar that I added inside my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    seekbar1 = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        int progressChanged = 0;
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            if (fromUser){
                progressChanged = progress;
                Toast.makeText(VesselFragment.this.getActivity(), "Ingots: " + progressChanged, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

This is my XML:

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:max="20" />
```

The problems are:

- When I drag along my seekbar it only updates when I let go of my finger.
- When I drag along my seekbar it sometimes changes its max value. A few times I dragged the bar all the way to the right and my Toast said that the progress is 5 or something like that.
- When I drag along my seekbar it sometimes happens that after I release my finger, my Toast displays that the value changes. The changes are random, sometimes it goes from a current value downwards then it stops and goes up and then it changes to some random value
  and continues.

I have no idea what causes his.

EDIT: Here is spam caused by this in logCat, when I wansn't even touching the phone:

```
07-20 20:09:40.723: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.723: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:40.738: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.738: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:40.758: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.758: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:40.773: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.773: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:40.788: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.788: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:40.873: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:40.873: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.093: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.093: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.138: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.138: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.158: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.158: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.173: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.173: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.208: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.208: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.223: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 16, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.223: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.238: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 16, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.238: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.258: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 17, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.258: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.273: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 17, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.273: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 17mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.288: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 18, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.288: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 17mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.308: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 18, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.308: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 18mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.323: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.323: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 18mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.338: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.338: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.358: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.358: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.373: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.373: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.388: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.388: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.408: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.408: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.423: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.423: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.438: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.438: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.573: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.573: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.588: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.588: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:42.593: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 19, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:42.593: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.203: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 17, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.203: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.243: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 16, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.243: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 17mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.258: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 16, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.258: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.273: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.273: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.288: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 15, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.288: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.308: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 14, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.308: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.323: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 13, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.323: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 14mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.338: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 12, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.338: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 13mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.358: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 12, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.358: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 12mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.373: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 11, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.373: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 12mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.388: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 10, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.388: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 11mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.408: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 9, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.408: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 10mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.423: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 8, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.423: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.443: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 8, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.443: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 8mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.458: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 7, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.458: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 8mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.473: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 7, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.473: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 7mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.493: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 6, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.493: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 7mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.508: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 6, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.508: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 6mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.523: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 5, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.523: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 6mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.538: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 5, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.538: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 5mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.558: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 5, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.558: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 5mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.573: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 4, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.573: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 5mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.588: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 4, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.588: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.608: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 4, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.608: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.613: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 4, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.613: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:43.613: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 4, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:43.613: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:48.368: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 12, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:48.368: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:48.473: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 12, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:48.473: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 12mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
07-20 20:09:48.478: D/ProgressBar(21895): setProgress = 12, fromUser = true
07-20 20:09:48.478: D/ProgressBar(21895): mProgress = 12mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 20
```

Comment: Use the fromUser boolean provided by `onProgressChanged` method!

Comment: I just modified the code and it didn't help

Comment: Where do you even call the Log command? In your given code it's not present.

Comment: It comes up in LogCat

Comment: I didn't create any logger, those messages just come out by themselves. You can clearly see in the log how the SeekerBar changes its value to random things even though I didn't even hold the phone.